# How can I use regular expressions to parse this format (ICAO flight plan remarks)?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to formulate a regular expression that can be used to extract information from a string that looks something like this ([ICAO Flight Plan Item 18](http://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Flight_Plan_Filling#Item_18)):

`DEP/S10 DEST/3W5 ALTN/1S2 RMK/TESTING, PLEASE IGNORE TYP/HOMEBUILT`

This long string has a series of individual "remarks" in it. Each remark consists of an indicator (e.g., `DEP`, `DEST`), a forward slash separator, and then the content itself.

For example, the above string has 5 individual remarks in it with the following indicators and content:

```
╔═══════════╦════════════════════════╗
║ Indicator ║ Content                ║
╠═══════════╬════════════════════════╣
║ DEP       ║ S10                    ║
║ DEST      ║ 3W5                    ║
║ ALTN      ║ 1S2                    ║
║ RMK       ║ TESTING, PLEASE IGNORE ║
║ TYP       ║ HOMEBUILT              ║
╚═══════════╩════════════════════════╝
```

I'd like to be able to parse out this information using a regular expression, with capturing groups for the indicator and content. I'm not sure if this is feasible. In particular, I'm finding it difficult to extract the content portions without also picking up the indicator for the next remark (i.e., match just the `S10` instead of `S10 DEST` for the first remark).

To start with the basics, the following regular expression can be used to extract just the indicators, but not the content:

`(\w+)\//g`

The content is a bit challenging - it can contain letters, numbers, spaces, and most any punctuation (excluding forward slashes). Basically, it needs to capture any character *up until* something of the form `\w+\/` (one or more characters followed by forward slash, which represents the start of the next remark). I've not been able to figure this out.

Is that something that is possible with regex, perhaps with a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)?

FYI, I'm hoping to do this using JavaScript's regex engine.

Comment: why not use `split()` on '/' then even indices are indicators and odd are content

Comment: you can try `\w+/[^/]+?(?= \w+/|$)` regex - https://regex101.com/r/nV6aY1/1

Comment: @depperm that would just give you [DEP, S10 DEST, 3W5 ALTN.......] not the Indicator/content "pairs"

Comment: this works: `/(\w+)\/(.*?)(?:$|(?=\w+\/))/g`; all that is left is to split each item on `/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use positive lookahead assertion

```
(\w+)\/([^\/]+?)(?= \w+\/|$)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/n4z99WwOw9SQCvVv)

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nV6aY1/2)

Then enumerate through all matches and for each match group 1 will be indicator and group 2 will be the content.

Answer (score 2):

Using the String `split()` method and the expression `/ ?(\w+\/)/` produces the following array, containing each remark indicator followed by its content.

```
var input = "DEP/S10 DEST/3W5 ALTN/1S2 RMK/TESTING, PLEASE IGNORE TYP/HOMEBUILT";
var remarks = input.split(/ ?(\w+)\//);
```

> ["", "DEP", "S10", "DEST", "3W5", "ALTN", "1S2", "RMK", "TESTING, PLEASE IGNORE", "TYP", "HOMEBUILT"]

If you want to remove the initial blank value, you can then also perform a `shift()` on the resulting array.

```
var input = "DEP/S10 DEST/3W5 ALTN/1S2 RMK/TESTING, PLEASE IGNORE TYP/HOMEBUILT";
var remarks = input.split(/ ?(\w+)\//);
remarks.shift();
```

> ["DEP", "S10", "DEST", "3W5", "ALTN", "1S2", "RMK", "TESTING, PLEASE IGNORE", "TYP", "HOMEBUILT"]

#### Sources

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split
3. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift

Answer (score 0):

Using `split` and a `for` loop to find indicators and content. Not the cleanest way but possible.

```js
var info='DEP/S10 DEST/3W5 ALTN/1S2 RMK/TESTING, PLEASE IGNORE TYP/HOMEBUILT';

var div=info.split('/');

var indicator=[];
indicator.push(div[0]);
var content=[];
var curr;
for(i=1;i<div.length-1;i++){
  curr=div[i];
  content.push(curr.substring(0,curr.lastIndexOf(' ')));
  indicator.push(curr.substring(curr.lastIndexOf(' ')+1));
}
content.push(div[div.length-1]);

console.log(indicator);
console.log(content);
```